# Cloudformation LayerVersion S3Bucket Using Parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-lambda-layers

I'm trying to use Cloudformation to package and deploy a simple "hello world" serverless app that uses a single Lambda Layer.  The issue I'm having is that the `LayerVersion` section in my CF template file doesn't seem to like the fact that I'm using a `!Ref` to specify the `S3Bucket` and `S3Key` values.  I don't want to hard-code these; nothing I've found in the documentation suggests that what I'm trying to do won't work, but it doesn't work :(

Here's the output of the `deploy` command that's failing:

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file out.yml --stack-name cftest-lambda --parameter-overrides S3BucketNameParameter=cftest-0eddf3f0b289f2c2 S3LambdaLayerNameParameter=cftest-lambda-layer-1602434332.zip --capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM

Waiting for changeset to be created..

Failed to create the changeset: Waiter ChangeSetCreateComplete failed: Waiter encountered a terminal failure state Status: FAILED. Reason: Transform AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31 failed with: Invalid Serverless Application Specification document. Number of errors found: 1. Resource with id [libs] is invalid. property Content not defined for resource of type AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
```

Here is the full CF template file:

```
cat template.yml 
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: An AWS Lambda application
Parameters: 
  S3BucketNameParameter: 
    Type: String
    Description: Bucket name for deployment artifacts
  S3LambdaLayerNameParameter:
    Type: String
    Description: Object name for lambda layer deployment artifact
Resources:
  helloworldfunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.8
      CodeUri: hello-world-with-layer/.
      Description: Hello world function to test cf using layers
      Timeout: 10
      # Function's execution role
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
        - AWSLambdaReadOnlyAccess
        - AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess
      Tracing: Active
      Layers:
        - !Ref libs
  libs:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      Content:
        S3Bucket: !Ref S3BucketNameParameter
        S3Key: !Ref S3LambdaLayerNameParameter
      CompatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.8
      LayerName: hello-world-lib
      Description: Dependencies for the hello-world-with-layer app.
```

Any suggestions on how to approach this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **correct properties** for [LayerContent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-property-layerversion-layercontent.html) are:

```
  Bucket: String
  Key: String
  Version: String
```

However, you are using (different names):

```
 S3Bucket: String
 S3Key: String
```

Comment: interestingly, cloudformation and sam docs don't agree :(  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-lambda-layerversion-content.html

Comment: @AJ. You are using `AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion`, not `AWS::Lambda::LayerVersion`. My link is to the documention of `AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion`.